# Ubuntu 18.04 | Installing a specific version of ansible

Tags: package-management, software-installation

May I ask if is there a way that I can install a specific version of ansible in ubuntu 18.04? (ansible version is 1.9.6)

Warm Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to [install it via apt](https://launchpad.net/%7Eansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible-1.9)

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible-1.9
sudo apt install ansible
```